# How to create custom edittext with button in android?

Tags: android, xml, button, android-edittext

How can I create this kind of edittext with button on android.
[image]

I've done relative layout but it just won't look very presentable.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use android:drawableRight property of EditText.Code as

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/enter_the_value"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```